# What is the file extension .bhtml and why use it?

Tags: html, web, server

Today I ran across a site that uses .bhtml as their served file extension. Is this just some proprietary internal php file? Is this used for SEO purposes? Why would anyone use it? Only thing on the subject I can find is [BabuHTML Embedded Software File](http://www.pppindia.com/babuhtml/) but there is not much online on this subject.

Example: http://www.euro.com.pl/zestawy-kina-domowego1.bhtml

Answer (score 6):

BHTML stands for **Broadcast Hypertext Markup Language**

BHTML is an XML compliant language based on a reduced set of HTML

***The bHTML platform provides a profile for TV-centric products and networks***. With bHTML, the ATSC wanted to define the application programming interfaces for Digital Television Application Software Environment (DASE) compliant receivers (set-top boxes).

BHTML is written in the emerging Extensible Markup Language (XML), a new language for advanced Web applications. BHTML scales back HTML elements and attributes by using parts of HTML 3.2, while it integrates synchronization functionality. The biggest difference between the two lies in the use of the Java software technology. ***BHTML is designed to be tightly integrated with the Application Execution Engine, or Java Virtual Machine, and with the Java framework.***

BHTML extends HTML by adding attributes for standardizing multimedia object descriptions within HTML OBJECT elements, using the SMIL SWITCH option and introducing an EVENT element to manage the actions to be taken when certain conditions are encountered. The BHTML specification also contains properties for defining 3D effects, controlling the volume of audio presentations, and for clipping and overflowing image areas. BHTML is an application of XML, so is case sensitive and requires all end-tags to be present.

For more info refer to this [link](http://xml.coverpages.org/xml.html#bhtml)

Comment: The last time that page was updated was 10 years ago. This seems like a very outdated technology. Why would this website choose to use .bhtml? It does not appear to rely on Java, maybe it did at one point. The domain was registered about 9 years ago so perhaps they just never felt the need to change anything...

Comment: ya that is another thing..but you wanted to know what is BHTML, so I answered that and I hope you got what you wanted in my answer!